# Tableau Left Join not returning all rows

Tags: left-join, tableau-api

I have data sources I want to join on an ID column.

The main table (left) ID are all non null. 
The main table is a WDC data source and the second is a table from MySQL database. 
So I did could not do the join outside of Tableau.
When retrieved alone, it can show all rows on incremental refresh. However when I make the join (left join) it shows only few rows. 
I first thought it was a filter issues so I disabled all filters. But the behavior is still the same. I even made a new fresh file with the data sources only but the behavior is the same. 
When I a make a blend all the rows can be retrieved, but I want to add a filter on the second data source so blending is not the solution for me. 
If someone could give one hint it will save my day.

Thanks

Comment: What are you joining together?

Comment: Does the join work outside of Tableau? Say ,in a SQL query?

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated the post. One data source is WDC and the other MySQL database. So to answer your question, no I can't try the join outside of Tableau.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the data types of the two columns? Maybe they differ which is why blending could give you desired results. Use a calculated join and cast to varchar

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and revert back to you